# Selecting a parent node in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

Here is a snippet of XML (there is much more) I'm working with, I'm trying to run an XPath expression to find the `ASIN` node in the `Item` section while confirming that the `Author` isn't `JK Rowling`.

I tried this: `/ItemSearchResponse/Items/Item/ItemAttributes[Author = "J.K. Rowling"]/parent::`

But it returns no matches, could you anyone guide me through accessing parent attributes?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<ItemSearchResponse> 
  <Items>
    <Request>
      <IsValid>True</IsValid>
      <ItemSearchRequest>
        <Condition>New</Condition>
        <DeliveryMethod>Ship</DeliveryMethod>
        <Keywords>Rowling Fiction English</Keywords>
        <MerchantId>Amazon</MerchantId>
        <ResponseGroup>Small</ResponseGroup>
        <SearchIndex>Books</SearchIndex>
      </ItemSearchRequest>
    </Request>
    <TotalResults>171</TotalResults>
    <TotalPages>18</TotalPages>
    <Item>
      <ASIN>0747557462</ASIN>
      <ItemAttributes>
        <Author>Sarah Brown</Author>
        <Author>Gil McNeil</Author>
        <Creator Role="Foreword">J.K. Rowling</Creator>
        <Manufacturer>Bloomsbury UK</Manufacturer>
        <ProductGroup>Book</ProductGroup>
        <Title>Magic</Title>
      </ItemAttributes>
    </Item>
  </Items>
</ItemSearchResponse>
```

Comment: It should throw a syntax error: `parent::` must be followed by some kind of NodeTest, e.g. `parent::*` or `parent::Item`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parent can be selected via `..` in XPath, but often it's cleaner to use predicates higher in the ancestry instead:

```
//Item[not(ItemAttributes/Author="J.K. Rowling")]/ASIN
```

will select all `ASIN` elements in `Item` elements that do not have an `ItemAttributes/Author` with string value of `"J.K. Rowling"`.